# Is there a way to emit HTML directly into an FsLab journal from the .fsx file?

Tags: f#, fslab

I'd like to emit some html (generated from my F# code) into a FsLab journal but cannot seem to find the correct incantation to make it happen.

If I have a function in my code that returns an html snippet is there a way to get this directly into the page without being surrounded by a `<pre>` tag?

---

I have tried, for example:

```
let f () = 
    """Some <b>bold</b> sample"""
let htmlContent = f ()
```

then

`(*** include-value:htmlContent ***)`

but the output is just the html code itself formatted like output.

I took a dive into the F# formatting GH pages and found the `(*** raw ***)` command so I also tried:

`(*** include-value:htmlContent, raw ***)`

but the output still gets surrounded by the `<pre>` & `<code>` tags.

Is it possible to simply emit raw html in this way without the `<pre>` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the latest version, then you can add custom HTML printers using `fsi.AddHtmlPrinter`. We need to improve FsLab docs, but this is also used by [F# Interactive Service in Atom](http://ionide.io/FsInteractiveService/htmlprinter.html).

To emit raw HTML, you can include something like this in your script:

```
(*** hide ***)
type Html = Html of string
#if HAS_FSI_ADDHTMLPRINTER
fsi.AddHtmlPrinter(fun (Html h) ->
  seq [], h)
#endif
```

Then, you should be able to create HTML nodes with:

```
let b = Html("""Some <b>bold</b> sample""")
(*** include-value:b ***)
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas, this seems like just what I was looking for but I don't seem to have fsi.AddHtmlPrinter (I get: "the field, constructor  or member is not defined") Do I need a newer version of fsi itself?

Comment: Ahhh - Ive got it now, this extn: https://github.com/ionide/FsInteractiveService/blob/1868abbdb53ce3db9fd8a3714cc93501c1b5dda4/src/FsInteractiveService/Main.fs yeah? - Thanks Tomas

Comment: @Stewart_R Sadly VS does not know about this method - which is why I use `#if` to hide it - but FsLab journal defines the `HAS_FSI_ADDHTMLPRINTER` symbol and adds the member to the `fsi` object, so it will run (even if VS thinks it will not!)